# What storage mechanism can I use to store the data related to user interaction of my website for a day

Tags: database

I store information about which items were accessed. That's it initially. I will store the id and type of item that were accessed. For example in a relational table it would be.

```
id type                view
1   dairy product      100
2   meat                88
```

Later on, in the end of the day, I will transfer this data to the actual table of the product.

products

```
id     name              view
1     Cheesy paradise    100
```

This is a web site, I don't want to update the table everytime the user visits a product. Because the products are in relational database and it would be very unprofessional. I want to make a service in Nodejs that when the user visits a product and stay for 5 secs and roll the page to the bottom I increment a high speed storage and in the end of the day I updated the related products in "one go".

I will handle only 300 visits in diferent products a day. But, of course, I want to my system to grow and it will handle keeping track of 1 thousand of products per minute, for example. In my mind when I though about this feature I thought about using Mongo. But I don't know it seems so much for this simple task. What tecnology can fit this situation better?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend MongoDB, since you are mostly "dumping" data into a database. That also allows you in the future to dump more information then you will now, no matter what kind of documents you dump now. Mongo is totally fine for a "dump" database structure.

Comment: Maybe MongoDB is a good choice. At least a keep this feature out of my relational database.